# Is it possible to write contents to S3 file simultaneously with two lambdas?

Tags: amazon-web-services, file, aws-lambda

Is it possible to write contents to S3 file simultaneously with two lambdas?

1. I have Ingestion Lambda 'A' which is writing to file err.txt once complete I will close the err.txt
2. I have another Data Load Lambda 'B' which I want to use to write to same file err.txt . I will open err.txt if present -- write the contents and close it. No issues.
3. If Lambdas 'A' and 'B' are running at the same time and writing to err.txt --> Is it possible? Will I get any technical challenges?

Comment: Yes, you will get the challenge that one lambda will simply overwrite the other result. "opening" and "closing" are not terms that exist within S3, you have GetObject and PutObject, one for reading, one for writing.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately no, this will not work the way you want.  Unlike a file on a file system there isn't an open/write/close type of flow with S3.  There is, as @luk2302 indicates, a `GetObject` and a `PutObject` call.  These are basically atomic - if there were two `PutObject` calls working at the same time then "last write wins".  Your first Lambda may get the file, update it, and then put it back.  But if another Lambda is doing the same then you may have lost the writes from the first one.

However, when I see a file name `err.txt` I wonder if you're trying to log some errors.  Make sure you take advantage of CloudWatch if you're logging things - it makes it much easier.

Comment: Thanks for help! It just a made up name. Ideally the text file is for business to look at for the fallouts during processing so I am planning to store in S3. Not sure if there is another solution to this else I will have to create two separate err files for each lambda.

Comment: Again, make sure you see what CloudWatch provides - it's super helpful for logging and debugging.